# How to type math equations in the post?

Tags: discussion, math-se, latex

I tried my best to find an example of how to post a math equation on Stack Overflow, but nothing worked. I'm familiar with [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) though. I found some people are saying you just need to add your equation between two doubled `$`s ( $$ f(x) = 2x $$), but it doesn't work for me. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: The stack overflow site is for programming questions. If you need more than basic formatting for mathematical notation your question is likely off-topic.

Comment: Let's start with the simple stuff: Stack Exchange is not a forum, it's a Question & Answer community.

Comment: As far as I know, MathJax is not activated on Stack Overflow.

Comment: While that post says LaTeX is off on stack overflow you can get quite far with <sub> and <sup> tags

Comment: You can only do it on math.stackexchange, mathoverflow.net and physics.stackexchange, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @RichardTingle: Also some useful entity references like `&minus;`, `&times;` etc., as well as `&nbsp;` for spacing.